# Make API call to Azure Service Management - how do I send the .pfx file in the call?

Tags: java, api, azure, pfx

I can successfully use Postman to make a call to  https://management.core.windows.net//services/hostedservices because I placed a .cer in Azure and a .pfx in my keystore.  Does anyone know how to make this call without using Postman?  How do I get the .pfx successfully in the call?

Java or JS answers would be helpful.

Comment: I wrote a blog post long time back on consuming Service Management API using Java. You can read the post here: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/08/25/consuming-windows-azure-service-management-api-in-java/. See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing @GauravMantri blog, please the steps below.

1. Create a self-signed certificate with Java tool `keytool`, command `?<java-path>/keytool -genkeypair -alias <domain> -keyalg RSA -keystore <keystore-filename>.jks 
   -keysize 2048 -storepass "<password>"`
2. Export the management certificate, command `<java-path>/keytool -v -export -file <path like D:>\<certname>.cer -keystore <keystore-filename>.jks 
   -alias <domain>`
3. Upload the management certificate in `MANAGEMENT CERTIFICATES` tab of `SETTINGS` tab on Azure classic portal.
   [image]
4. Create the Service Management Client with the certificate jks file using Azure SDK for Java.

   ```
   import java.net.URI;

   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration;
   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.utils.KeyStoreType;
   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.configuration.ManagementConfiguration;
   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.ComputeManagementService;
   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.ComputeManagementClient;
   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.network.NetworkManagementService;
   import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.network.NetworkManagementClient;

   String uri = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
   String subscriptionId = "<subscription-id>";
   String keyStorePath = "<path>\<keystore-filename>.jks";
   String keyStorePassword = "<password>";

   Configuration config =  Configuration config =     ManagementConfiguration.configure(
               new URI(uri),
               subscriptionId,
               keyStoreLocation, // the file path to the JKS
               keyStorePassword, // the password for the JKS
               KeyStoreType.jks // flags that I'm using a JKS keystore
             );
   ManagementClient client = ManagementService.create(config);
   // Or other management clients, such as ComputerManagementClient
   // ComputeManagementClient computeManagementClient = ComputeManagementService.create(config);
   ```